# Comparing a value of a row with the value of the previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server that stores geology samples, and there is a rule that must be adhered to.

The rule is simple, a **"DUP_2" sample must always come after a "DUP_1" sample** (sometimes they are loaded inverted)

```
CREATE TABLE samples (
    id INT
    ,name VARCHAR(5)
    );
    
INSERT INTO samples VALUES (1, 'ASSAY');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES (2, 'DUP_1');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES (3, 'DUP_2');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES (4, 'ASSAY');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES (5, 'DUP_2');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES (6, 'DUP_1');
INSERT INTO samples VALUES (7, 'ASSAY');
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ASSAY |
| 2 | DUP_1 |
| 3 | DUP_2 |
| 4 | ASSAY |
| 5 | DUP_2 |
| 6 | DUP_1 |
| 7 | ASSAY |

In this example I would like to show all rows where name **equal to** 'DUP_2' and predecessor row (using ID) name is **different** from 'DUP_1'.

In this case, it would be row 5 only.

I would appreciate very much if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LAG()` window function or you can use `LEAD()` - they are identical except for the way in which they are ordered. That is - `LAG(name) OVER ( ORDER BY id )` is the same as `LEAD(name) OVER ( ORDER BY id DESC )`. (You can [read more about these functions here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9127/sql-server-window-functions-lead-and-lag/).)

```
WITH s1 ( id, name, prior_name ) AS (
    SELECT id, name, LAG(name) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS prior_name
      FROM samples
)
SELECT id, name
  FROM s1
 WHERE name = 'DUP_2'
   AND COALESCE(prior_name, 'DUMMY') != 'DUP_1';
```

The reason for the `COALESCE()` at the end with the `DUMMY` value is that the first value won't have a `LAG()`; it will be `NULL`; and we want to return the `DUP_2` record in this case since it doesn't follow a `DUP_1` record.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             lag(name) over (order by id) as prev_name
      from samples s
     ) s
where name = 'DUP_2' and (prev_name <> 'DUP_1' or prev_name is null)
```